# Can't link out from amp-autocomplete when selecting a result?

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to use the AMP amp-autocomplete component as an autosuggest search feature with API endpoint, but I cannot get the results to link out to the url value. Everything is working as expected with the results populating dynamically.

When selecting a result, the `data-value="{{title}}"` appears in the input but I cannot get the navigateTo action to redirect the page to the result `{{url}}`.

I've tried using `navigateTo` with `on="select:"` and `on="tap:"` with no luck. I have also tried wrapping the result in a `href="{{url}}"` element but that didn't work either.

```
<form class="sample-form" method="post" target="_top">
      <amp-autocomplete filter="token-prefix"
        filter-value="title"
        id="autosuggest"
        min-characters="2"
        src="//example.com/api/search"
        [src]="'//example.com/api/search?q=' + (searchQuery || '')">
        <input type="search"
        name="title"
        id="search"
        [value]=searchQuery on="input-debounced:AMP.setState({searchQuery: event.value})">
        <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-custom" >
          <div data-value="{{title}}" value="{{url}}" class="results-items" on="select:AMP.navigateTo(url=event.value)">
            <span class="results-item__type">{{type}}</span>
            <span class="results-item__title">{{title}}</span>
          </div>
        </template>
      </amp-autocomplete>
    </form>
```

The expected result is similar to the https://tasty.co/ website search functionality with autosuggestions that link out when selected.

Answer (score 1):

you actually can do this by using this Template:

```
<template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-custom">
   <div class="slug-item" data-value="{{ title}}">
       <a href="{{url}}">{{ title }}</a>   
   </div>
</template>
```

Be aware, you can just test this with Google Chrome in Mobile Mode.

Comment: Link doesn't work in `amp-autocomplete` for some reason

Answer (score 0):

According to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63341010/13199446) you can try to add `on="select"` event to the `amp-autocomplete` element: `on="select:AMP.navigateTo(url=event.value, target=_blank)"`.

Codepen Example: https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/rNeVoVo

Not sure if you can use `a` element in `amp-autocomplete`.